# Where is the IBM i Telnet (TN5250) Logon Exit point

Tags: ibm-midrange

On the "Work with Registration Information" page (WRKREGINF), I see logon exit point for the FTP and REXEC Servers (QIBM_QTMF_SVR_LOGON & QIBM_QTMX_SVR_LOGON). But I can't seem to be able to find the Telnet (TN5250) logon exit point.  Is there no such beast?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaiw/rzaiwprogramtypes.htm)...

> The Telnet server response time for your initial session request
> includes any time that it takes for the server to call, process, and
> return the QIBM_QTG_DEVINIT exit program

Comment: hmm.  I just tested out this exit point. It is not what I expected. It only calls the exit point during the very first login, where it needs to establish the connection to the device.  Once the device connection is established, it does not call that exit point again.  So, it won't call the exit program if the user logs out and logs back in again using a different user ID and password.  I'm trying to implement Two Factor Authentication and would like an exit point that will get called every time user tries to login.

Comment: I believe you could configure the system to disconnect on sign-off...

Comment: it looks like this exit point will not work for my situation.  My 2-FA process requires user to enter a access code, which means that it will need to display a screen.  This exit point failed if the program has a DSPF file.